How do I setup another BT adapter after previous one didnt setup?
I built a new PC and to get my bluetooth devices connected to it, i initially used a cheap Bluetooth adapter, which in order to setup & install it's drivers, told me to disable memory integrity in Windows Defender for proper installation. So after this, when i clicked on the setup.exe file, the drivers seemed curroupted and were in Chinese and the installation wizard couldn't even display it properly (it showed boxes).
So even after disabling mem. integrity, the adapter's drivers didn't work, and i decided to return it. Thankfully no virus / malware were installed, i ensured same with deep scans. But I couldn't re-enable memory integrity due to "conflicting drivers", so I used pnputil /delete-driver oemXX.inf /uninstall /force (specifically oem35, 32, 33, 34, 26, 28 were listed as conflicting drivers) to remove them and then was able to successfully re-enabled memory integrity.
Now, I have a decent TP-Link 4.0 Bluetooth adapter, which is listed as plug n' play for Windows 10/11, no drivers needed. When i first plugged it in win11 desktop, it didn't detect devices, so i thought it was defective - but It worked on my Windows 10 laptop, after fixing a "driver error" which popped up using the Device Manager's troubleshooter & a restart.
However, on my Windows 11 desktop, the adapter & bluetooth turns on but doesn't detect any devices nor shows up in others. Could I have accidentally deleted a crucial driver / file needed for BT while fixing the cheap adapter's issue? Or there's a different problem here? What could I do now to successfully get my new adapter working? Thank you.
Edit: Here's a updated screenshot of the device manager in my Windows 11 desktop after uninstalling the device and restarting. Also, the adapter is this one - TPLink UB400 4.0 (https://www.tp-link.com/in/home-networking/adapter/ub400/)


"Could I have accidentally deleted a crucial driver / file needed for BT while fixing the cheap adapter's issue?" - No; Provide a screenshot of Device Manager with the USB device in question highlighted. If its the UB400 I suspect it does not support Windows 11.

@Ramhound thanks for replying, here's a screenshot of Device manager - https://i.ibb.co/wL8x1Ct/image.png, and yes it is the UB400 Adapter (https://www.tp-link.com/in/home-networking/adapter/ub400/), but it says on it's website and amazon page that it is compatible with Windows 11? Do I need to buy the UB500 5.0 one to work on windows 11? Please suggest, thanks.

Thsi Bluetooth adapter does not require any third-party drivers on Win 10 and Win 11. Uninstall all third-party drivers, turn ON all important security thing you turned Off and reboot PC. Next simple plug the dongle in and Windows will install drivers. However its better to run Windows recovery first (DISM) because it looks you removed some important INF files.

@MikePetrichenko thanks for replying, can you please elaborate more on how can i check and uninstall third party bluetooth devices' drivers (which may have been installed due to the previous adapter)? Tried to find a way online but I am confused on how to do the same properly... Thanks!

@Ramhound I have an update, I uninstalled the device from device manager and did a restart (didnt unplug), and now this is what is looks like in device manager - https://i.ibb.co/VMqdHBr/image.png . but still no devices detected nor it's being shown in other devices.

That screenshot isn't accessible.  If it's not already been added to the question body you should do that.

@kartik As from your last update: all looks OK and drivers are installed correctly. What kind of device you want to find? Is your device in discoverable (aka pairing) mode? To be able to find PC it also must be switched to discoverable mode.
